# Jenkins pipeline is taking too much time to execute

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have written this jenkins pipeline to ssh to a server and execute docker commands but it is taking too much time to execute. Around 3 hrs and still going.

```
    pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'JDK 1.8'
    }
    stages {
        stage('mvn Clean') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'mvn clean'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('mvn Install'){
            steps{
                script{
                    sh 'mvn install'
                }
            }
        }

    

       stage('mvn Deploy'){
    steps{
        script{
            def deployOutput = sh(script: 'mvn deploy', returnStdout: true).trim()
            def warUrl = deployOutput =~ /Uploaded to maven-repo: (\S+\.war)/
            if (warUrl) {
                def extractedUrl = warUrl[0][1]
                echo "Uploaded WAR File URL: ${extractedUrl}"
                env.WAR_URL = extractedUrl
            } else {
                error "No WAR files found in deploy output"
            }
        }
    }
}

        stage('Deploy'){
            steps{
                script{
                    sh 'eval `ssh-agent -s`'
                    sshagent(credentials: ['SHHCRED']) {
                    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com "cd docker && aws s3 --profile abc cp ${env.WAR_URL} social.war && sudo docker image build -t social ."'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am i making a mistake here, what are some possible solutions, and is there any error in code which i am not able to catch.

Comment: are you trying to deploy your project from a local repo or form git platform ??

Comment: @Mohamedaminebenhassen from aws codecommit

Comment: Which stage takes the longest?

Comment: @MB mvn deploy takes the longest

Comment: The mvn deploy command doesn't take as long when running it locally I assume?

Comment: @MB If i add any docker command in deploy stage then it takes a lot of time, other pipeline works fine

Comment: Does this also happen when running docker commands from your Jenkins host (from the machine terminal instead of the pipeline)?

Comment: @MB no, it does not happen then